# Problems installing PHPMailer on Windows 2008 server r2 configured w/ iss 7.0

Tags: php, server, phpmailer, windows-server-2008-r2

Can anyone please give me detailed instructions on installing php mailer on a windows 2008 server2 with ISS 7.0?

I know I have to download php mailer from the site, but after that I have no idea what to do, and the github instructions are unclear.

**So far I've taken these steps:**
1. Installed and Configured PHP with ISS
2. Installed Compiler via the windows setup.
3. Downloaded php mailer from site

Note: My knowledge of how to use the compiler and php is limited so if anyone can explain how to install php mailer and insert it into one of my projects I'll be eternally grateful. Thanks!

Comment: there's nothing TO install. it's just a bunch of .php files. drop them somewhere PHP can find them (e.g. in the include_path) and that should be it.

Comment: You mean drop them in the php folder? Where's the include path?

Comment: You could try [reading the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path). They're very good. As Marc B said, PHPMailer is a bunch of PHP files just like the ones you're already working with, so just put the whole unzipped folder into the same location and load the autoloader from your script as the readme tells you. If you're really that new to PHP, you should learn to do this the right way, so I suggest you [learn how to use composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md).

Comment: I added the project files directly to the directory, but I get a 500 internal error when I launch the site. Do I need an smtp server installed in iss in addition to php, compiler, and php mailer so that i can successfully send an email